# Unequal bin widths in pgfplots density histogram

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, graphs

In the [pgfplots manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf), it talks about density histograms with equal bin widths/ranges. Is it possible to make a density histogram with specified unequal bin widths/ranges?

For example, if I set xmin=1, xmax=3 and bins=2, it will automatically make 2 bins, [1,2) and [2,3]. Can I make the bins [1, 1.2] and (1.2, 3]?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. My first thought would be stacking plots in the same graph while using a foreach loop with variable bin width. Alternatively I'd try to hack the process. Jake probably knows how to do either.

Comment: It would be nice, if you could provide some dummy data and an MWE so we can concentrate on the *solution* ...